# AspNet.Identity.Core 2 Add Custom fields to IdentityUser - Error Creating user

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add 3 additional fields to the user's identity:
aId (int), FirstName (string), LastName (string)

I created a new model, inheriting IdentityUser:

```
public class SysUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int aId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public SysUser() { }
}
```

I'm running into an error when trying to register a new user:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        SysUser user = new SysUser
        {
            UserName = userModel.UserName,
            Email = userModel.Email,
            FirstName = userModel.FirstName,
            LastName = userModel.LastName),
            aId = userModel.aId
        };
            
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userModel.RoleName))
            _userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, userModel.RoleName);
        return result;
    }
```

I receive the error on this line:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
```

error:
{"Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'API.Models.SysUser'."}

I added the 3 fields to the aspnetusers table and i've updated the entity.
I have verified that properties match the database column name.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: is the `aId` refferencing another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. Needed to change IdentityUser to SysUser in AuthContext.cs.

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<SysUser>
```

and update the UserManager variable in my AuthRepo:

```
_userManager = new UserManager<SysUser>(new UserStore<SysUser>(_ctx));
```